# Second order linear inhomogeneous PDE with Neumann BCs and variable coefficient

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am having trouble finding the solution of the following PDE with a variable coefficient:

$u_{xx}+u_{yy}-i p(x,y) u=-f(x,y)$

where $i=\sqrt{-1}$, where $u,f\in\mathbb{C}$, where $p\in\mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}$, and with the following Neumann Boundary Conditions:

$u_x(0,y)=0$, $u_x(a,y)=0$, $u_y(x,0)=0$, $u_y(x,b)=0$

where we have some rectangular domain $0\leq x\leq a$ and $0\leq y\leq b$. Of course, because of these Neumann Boundary Conditions the source $f(x,y)$ must satisfy the following condition:

$\iint_S f(x,y) ds=0$

If I assume that $p(x,y)$ is a positive constant, I was able to solve this problem, where the solution is of the following form:

$u=\sum_r \sum_s C_{r,s}\cos mx \cos ny$

where the Fourier coefficients $C_{r,s}$ can be found by inserting this solution in the PDE, then multiplying on both sides by $\cos mx \cos ny$ and integrating on both sides. I also verified that I get the same $u$ at a given $(x,y)$ using finite elements. Because of the boundary conditions, we have $m=r\pi/a$ and $n=s\pi/b$.

However, with a variable coefficient $p(x,y)$, I do not get the same result using finite elements if I assume that the solution is of the above form and following the same procedure to calculate the $C_{r,s}$, as detailed in the previous paragraph.

At first, I thought it was because the $p(x,y)$ I used was piecewise smooth, but I also have the same problem using $p(x,y)=\cos\frac{\pi x}{a}\cos\frac{\pi y}{b}+2$.

Any hint on how to solve this problem would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

I realized that my problem might come from the way I calculate the Fourier coefficients, so here's a bit more details on how I calculate $C_{r,s}$. The 2 partial derivatives are given by:

$u_{xx}=-\sum_r\sum_s m^2 C_{r,s}\cos mx \cos ny$

$u_{yy}=-\sum_r\sum_s n^2 C_{r,s}\cos mx \cos ny$

Inserting these back in the PDE gives:

$-\sum_r\sum_s (m^2+n^2+ip(x,y)) C_{r,s}\cos mx \cos ny=-f(x,y)$

Multiplying on both sides by $\cos mx \cos ny$ and integrating, we get:

$\int_{-b}^b\int_{-a}^a (m^2+n^2+ip(x,y)) C_{r,s}\cos^2 mx \cos^2 ny {\rm d}x{\rm d}y=\int_{-b}^b\int_{-a}^a f(x,y)\cos mx \cos ny{\rm d}x{\rm d}y$

Solving for $C_{r,s}$ we finally get:

$C_{r,s}=\frac{4\int_{0}^b\int_{0}^a f(x,y)\cos mx \cos ny{\rm d}x{\rm d}y}{(m^2+n^2)ab+i4\int_{0}^b\int_{0}^a p(x,y)\cos^2 mx \cos^2 ny {\rm d}x{\rm d}y}$

Where the "4" comes from rearranging the boundaries of the integrals of these even functions (of course, $p$ and $f$ are also even function, I forgot to mention that).

Like I said, it works if $p(x,y)=constant$, but it does't seem to work for a variable one like $p(x,y)=\cos\frac{\pi x}{a}\cos\frac{\pi y}{b}+2$. Any clues on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My first thought is to try splitting up the real and imaginary parts of the solution $u$, and accordingly the real and imaginary parts of $p(x,y)$ and $f(x,y)$, so get a coupled system of PDE's.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the coefficients $C_{r,s}$ are complex. Therefore, when I solve the Fourier integral, shouldn't it already make the real and imaginary parts equal on both sides of the equation? In other words, I guess we could solve $A+iB=C+iD$ as $A=C$ and $B=D$, but the result should be the same, no? At least, it seems to work if we set $p(x,y)=P$ (constant). Perhaps my assumption on the form of the solution is wrong if $p(x,y)$ is not constant.